# How to declare same attributes for two android themes?

Tags: android, inheritance, themes, multiple-inheritance, styling

I have to declare some base values for my App (like `windowNoTitle`).In some activities the `Theme.AppCompat.Light` theme is needed cause of transparent background images. They need a white background but `` In  others the `Theme.AppCompat` theme will be used for styling.

My App uses `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`. So I need to extend a Compat theme. I can't apply the default values as parent and apply the style via theme name.

How to apply the default values to both themes but not repeat my self. Is it possible to declare "style variables"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Extend the theme with two different name and then use at the particular component.

Comment: Won't work. because because the inherit style of the AppCompat theme will override the Settings from the name. I've  solved the problem now with a custom child theme with all the needed property from the light theme but thats not the perfect solution